# Django read data from an sync_to_async db call

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm trying to read some data that I need to get from the database in an async function. So i'm wrapping it with channels sync_to_async function. Now the issue is how do I access the actual data that I retrieved from the database? Currently it just outputs as this: `<channels.db.DatabaseSyncToAsync object at 0x7f7b672ea6d0>`

Code:

```
from ...models import admin_list
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

def get_admins():
    return admin_list.objects.values('name')

    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        admin_names = database_sync_to_async(get_admins)
        print(admin_names)
```

Answer (score 5):

**`database_sync_to_async`** returns a `awaitable`, you have to await on it.

```
from ...models import admin_list
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

@database_sync_to_async
def get_admins():
    return admin_list.objects.values('name')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    admin_names = await get_admins()
    print(admin_names)
```

Comment: That won't work. It returns the following error `django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async`

Comment: Fixed it with this line in settings.py `os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"`